# Google Map Direction issue in cordova ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-maps, cordova

When I click on direction link it shows the direction from other place instead of showing from current location to destination.

I am working on Cordova, in android it's shows the direction from current location to destination, this issue is not there but in iOS 11 version I am getting this issue, in iOS 10 version it is working.

I used below URL for Google Map Direction where it will auto fill my current location but it is shows other location instead of current location.

```
var mapLocationUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=" + lat + "," + long;

window.open(encodeURI(mapLocationUrl), '_system', 'location=yes');
```

---

```
function geocodeAddress() {
    var address = $("#address1").text() + $("#address2").text();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var p = results[0].geometry.location;
            var lat = p.lat();
            var lng = p.lng();
            datastring = 'compId=' + compid + "&lat=" + lat + "&long=" + lng;
        }
    });
}
```

---

[Screen shot added for not getting the direction from auto detecting current location instead of that, it pointing some other place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHIDi.png)

Comment: how is lat and long calculated, can you post code of that.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth. it is calculated by gecoder but that lat and long is for destination, code which i used -
function geocodeAddress() {
    var address = $("#address1").text() + $("#address2").text();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var p = results[0].geometry.location;
            var lat = p.lat();
            var lng = p.lng();
            datastring = 'compId=' + compid + "&lat=" + lat + "&long=" + lng;
        }
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript library

```
<html>
   <head>
      ...    
         ...
         <style>
         #map {
         height: 100%;
                 top: 0px;
             }
         </style>    
             </head>
             <body>
             ...
             <div id="map"></div>
             ...
         <script>
          function initMap() {
         var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

                         var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

                         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                             zoom: 10,
                             center: {
                                 lat: 0.0..,
                                 lng: 0.0...
                             },
                             disableDefaultUI: true,
                             mapTypeControl: false
                         });
         map.setTilt(45);
         directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
         calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
         }
         function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                         directionsService.route({
                             origin: startLocation, //String or lat long
                             destination: endLocation, //String or lat long
                             waypoints: waypoints, //[String or lat long]
                             optimizeWaypoints: true, 
                             travelMode: 'DRIVING'
         }, function (response, status) {
         if (status === 'OK') {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
         } else {
                                 if (status == "ZERO_RESULTS")
                                     window.alert("Wrong address found");
                                 else if (status == "MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED")
                                     window.alert("Maximun address entered ");
                                 else
                                     window.alert("Wrong address");
                             }
         });
                     }
      </script>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=B****&callback=initMap">
      </body>
      <html>
```

---

Or Directly launch Google and Apple maps for direction.

```
function Dir() {
    var saddr = startLocation;
    var daddr = endLocation;
    //Load Apple Maps
    var url = "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=" + daddr + "&dirflg=d&t=m"
    //Launch google maps
    var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=My+Location&destination=" + daddr + "&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate"
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

For more Details
[Apple URL Scheme Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

Comment: I tried using origin=Current+Location, it shows the direction from current location to destination but in top portion of map i.e in source address field it display as Dropped pin (instead of Your Location/My Location) and one thing i observed that google map direction works properly only if google map runs in background and it only happens in iOS 11,12,13 version.

Comment: in real device - iPhone 7 (v11.3.1),iPad retina mini (v13.2)

Comment: I added the screenshot, pls check it in my above question  : Screen shot added for not getting the direction from auto detecting current location instead of that, it pointing some other place

Comment: If you tryed below one
`var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=My+Location&destination=" + Destination Address + "&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate"
window.location.href = url`

Comment: Or go to Apple Maps for ios platform => 
`var url = "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=" + daddr + "&dirflg=d&t=m"`